# Как должна выглядеть правильная архитектура

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте. Хочу спроектировать правильную архитектуру приложения следуя MVVM. 
Мне необходимо смоделировать работу видеокамеры. Я выделил два основных класса: `Видеокамера` и `Телевизор`. в первом будет вестись запись видео, а во втором трансляция записанных видео.

`Model`

```
class VideoCamera
{
    public Video video {get; set;}
    public void Record(){...} //запись видео
}
class TV
{
    public Video video {get;set;}
    public void Play(){...} //проигрывание видео
}
```

Понятно, что метод `Record()` должен выполнятся в фоновом потоке, я хочу использовать BackgroundWorker для этого и передавать раз в 1 секунду часть записанного видео в класс TV. Но метод Rerort() в BW, как я понял, не останавливает фоновой поток, не дожидается завершения обработчика события, который он генерирует. То есть получается мне нужно передать копию Video из `камеры` в `tv`.

Как правильно спроектировать `VM` этих классов для достижения этих целей?

Comment: А в чем заключается моделирование?

Comment: @Arheus, я хочу узнать как правильно передавать данные которые подгружаются из фонового потока в основной, например раз в секунду.

Comment: Да тут то ничего сложно нет и с MVVM это не связано. Доставать из потока просто — в фоновом потоке строка: Dispatcher.Invoke(тут метод из потка ui). В метод передаешь объект и ссылки на него больше не держишь ( что бы крит секции не создавать). Dispatcher соответственно от потока UI (можно и другого, но зависит от задачи).

Comment: По факту 1 секунда не пожатого видео — это может быть много (по объему, допустим 24 кадра в секунду, fullhd, это 5-6 Mb х 24 = 120-140Mb). Многовато для посекундного выделения-удаления. Я бы или покадрово сжато "передавал" или, если у тебя просто имитация, то сам поток можно перекидывать с камеры в output. В общем, конкретизируй вопросы, т.к. задача весьма расплывчатая сейчас.